# Put any application in the background in Android

Tags: android, background

I know how to put any application in the foreground but I would now put any application in the background. Ie, each application i want.
I searched a lot on google but I have not found a solution.
Have you any idea how?
I tried to display the home but it does not work :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my all code (its a test code), i launch map app and i want just after, puting it in backgroud:

```
    List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList =  retreivedAllApplicationsInstalled();      

    ActivityManager actMngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = actMngr.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo pi : runningAppProcesses) {

        String[] testPklist = pi.pkgList;

        if(pi.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND){
            for(String tp : testPklist){
                if(tp.equals("com.google.android.apps.maps")){

                       //launch map application
                       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                       PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                       i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                       i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                       startActivity(i);

                }
            }

        }

    }
    //try to put back all applications on displaying home
    Intent back = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    back.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(back);
```

Comment: AFAIK, that should work to bring up the home screen. What does LogCat show when you execute your above code?

Comment: Logcat does not talk when i execute this part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app to run in the background you should use something called a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You can find more information on the link. But remember that background process drain battery, so use it with care.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I dont want implement a background service, because i want put in background other application than mine

Comment: If i encapsulate in a service the part of code which launch the map activity (in this example), and if i ask to that service to be on background, is will work ????

Comment: Yes, a service will let you run an activity on the background.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read the explanation of services and unfortunately is not what I want. I want to set a background application that was active before, not directly start an application in the background.

Comment: "because i want put in background other application than mine" You can do that only by putting something else (either your application or something you can launch with an intent) in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem in my code:
I run a activity 'map', which execute and then my code below (to put in background) is never launched.......